# IF function within pivot calculated field

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to create a calculated field but this keeps erroring out.

```
=IF(CASES_ORDERED_PIVOT-CASES_RECEIVED_PIVOT<0,
     IF(PO_ITEM_LINE_STATUS ="X"), 0, 
     CASES_ORDERED_PIVOT-CASES_RECEIVED_PIVOT))
```

Comment: can you add a description of what you want to achieve? Just by looking at the formula I'm a little lost...

Answer (score 1):

`IF(PO_ITEM_LINE_STATUS ="X")` This is a wrong nest for an If, where is the "true" and "else" value in the conditional?

Try:

```
=IF(CASES_ORDERED_PIVOT-CASES_RECEIVED_PIVOT<0,IF(PO_ITEM_LINE_STATUS ="X", 0, CASES_ORDERED_PIVOT-CASES_RECEIVED_PIVOT),"")

=IF([Column1]-[Column2]<0,IF([Column3]="X",TRUE,ELSE),ELSE)

or

=IF([Column1]-[Column2]<0,TRUE,IF([Column3]="X",TRUE,ELSE))
```